# Everywhere discontinuous function

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and $\mathcal{A}$ be a recovering of $X$ (i.e. a collection of subsets of $X$ that accomplishes $\bigcup\mathcal{A}=X$) such that, for every $A\in\mathcal{A}$ there is a function $f_A:A\to\{0,1\}$ satisfying $\{0,1\}\subseteq f_A[A\cap U]$ for every open subset $U$ of $X$ that meet $A$, i.e. $A\cap U\neq \emptyset$. Within this conditions, how to prove that there is a function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ everywhere discontinous in $X$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\kappa$ be the cardinality of $\mathcal{A}$; thus, one can write $\mathcal{A} = \{A_{\alpha}:\alpha<\kappa\}$. As $\bigcup\mathcal{A}=X$, for every $x\in X$, the set $O_x=\{\alpha<\kappa:x\in A_\alpha\}$ is not empty; thus there is an ordinal $\alpha_x$ that is the minimum of $O_x$. Since the minimum is unique, the relation $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as 
$$f(x)=f_{\alpha_{x}}(x)$$
is a function. Without loss of generality, one can assume that $f(x)=0$.

Given an open set $U$ ox $X$ such that $x\in U$, the fact that $\mathcal{A}$ is a cover for $X$ testify that $P_U=\{\alpha<\kappa:A_\alpha\cap U\neq\emptyset\}$  is not empty; again, there is an ordinal $\alpha_U$ that is the minimum of $P_U$. As $A_{\alpha_{U}}\cap U\neq\emptyset$, the hypothesis avers that 
$$\{0,1\}=f_{\alpha_{U}}[A_{\alpha_U}\cap U]$$
Therefore, there is a $z\in A_{\alpha_U}\cap U$ such that $f_{\alpha_U}(z)=1$. Now, by the minimality of $\alpha_U$, one can assert that $\alpha_z=\alpha_U$; ergo, $f(z)=1$.

Now, as $\{0,1\}$ is a discrete space, $\{0\}$ is a neighbourhood of $f(x)$ that does not contain $f[U]$, testifying that $f$ cannot be continuous.